# Opening attribute table using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, qgis-python-console

Is it possible to open an attribute table from the Python Console or through a Python script in QGIS?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you can, at least with the latest master version and 1.8. It is a [method exposed via iface](https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a338446c244912bc8a736c99b8b3a61a6)

```
// C++ (signature)
void showAttributeTable (QgsVectorLayer *l)

# PyQGIS (example)
iface.showAttributeTable(iface.activeLayer())
```

You will need a preexisting reference to a QgsVectorLayer.

For direct editing of features it is also a [method exposed via iface](https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a11b90f38afd09ac5e9f363933ee4a509):

```
// C++ (signature)
bool openFeatureForm (QgsVectorLayer *l, QgsFeature &f, bool updateFeatureOnly=false)

# PyQGIS (example)
iface.openFeatureForm(iface.activeLayer(), feature, False)
```

You will need a preexisting reference to a QgsVectorLayer and a QgsFeature in both cases. The feature form opened and whether it is editable are dependent upon app settings and whether the feature's layer is in edit mode.

Comment: The Python example worked well for me when in Python console. However, I tried to run this script in Processing, where the layer = processing.getObject() of a loaded layer. From iface.showAttributeTable(layer), I got Name Error: global name 'iface' is not defined. Any suggestions?

Comment: @dakcarto You need to import iface with  'from qgis.utils import iface'

Comment: @user25976 The reference to `iface` only works for the console or scripts run from within QGIS, including plugins like Processing. For the console, it is auto-imported for convenience, with all other cases needing the `import` of `qgis.utils`. This is described at the [beginning of the PyQGIS cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html). You can not access `iface` in a standalone app, since the Python modules do not instantiate the QGIS desktop GUI application.

Comment: @dakcarto iface.openFeatureForm(iface.activeLayer(), feature, False) This is useful when we want to edit the selected feature but if i want to add a new feature how can i do that? without feature