# Hiding column in attribute table by using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

Is there a way to hide a column in the attribute table by using PyQGIS?

By hiding I do not mean hiding only the edit widget, I would like to hide the column completely.

It is possible to achieve that by right-clicking on the column in the attribute table and selecting `'Hide column'` or `'Organize columns...'` but I did not find a way how to do it by using PyQGIS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### For QGIS versions QGIS 2.16 and higher

Let's define the following handy function:

```py
def setColumnVisibility( layer, columnName, visible ):
    config = layer.attributeTableConfig()
    columns = config.columns()
    for column in columns:
        if column.name == columnName:
            column.hidden = not visible
            break
    config.setColumns( columns )
    layer.setAttributeTableConfig( config )
```

And then you can call it to hide or show columns in the attribute table. For example:

```py
vLayer = iface.activeLayer()
setColumnVisibility( vLayer, 'FIRST_COLUMN', False ) # Hide FIRST_COLUMN
setColumnVisibility( vLayer, 'area', False ) # Hide area column
setColumnVisibility( vLayer, 'FIRST_COLUMN', True ) # Show FIRST_COLUMN
setColumnVisibility( vLayer, 'area', True ) # Show area column
```

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to refresh/reload an open attribute table without having to close and open it to update changes in the column visibilities?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a direct way to do that. Moreover, `QgsAttributeTableDialog` is not exposed through the API.

Comment: I realized opening and closing it is good enough: `attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName() == u'QgsAttributeTableDialog' or d.objectName() == u'AttributeTable']
attrTables[0].close()
iface.showAttributeTable(lyr)` https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231574/how-to-close-all-or-distinct-attribute-table-with-pyqgis and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68332/opening-attribute-table-using-pyqgis

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use the [`setColumnHidden()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableConfig.html#aacf25bd8fcbb90cef0fdcbf70a4ec401) method of the `QgsAttributeTableConfig` class.

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

def hide_one_column(layer_name: str, column_name: str, column_hidden: bool) -> None:
    """
    Hides or shows a single column in the attribute table of a layer
    Parameters:
    ==========
    :param layer_name: name of the layer
    :param column_name: name of the target column
    :param column_hidden: if the column should be hidden
    """
    
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    column_index = layer.fields().indexOf(column_name)

    layer_attr_table_config = layer.attributeTableConfig()
    layer_attr_table_config.setColumnHidden(column_index, column_hidden)

    layer.setAttributeTableConfig(layer_attr_table_config)

    return

hide_one_column('gis_osm_buildings', 'osm_id', True) # Hide "osm_id" field
```

*P.S.* To notice applied changes one must close and open the attribute table.

Comment: This function affects the wrong column, if there are action-columns before. German Carillos solution takes this into account.