# Closing attribute table with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, close

I have a QGIS 2.18.0 plugin which updates a join between two layers (spatial and non-spatial layer).

QGIS crashes when I run the plugin and the attribute table of the joined layer is open. There is no crash when the attribute table is closed or an attribute table of another layer is open.

The last two commands that the plugin runs are:

```py
....
PUNKTE_OS.addJoin(joinObject)
        
PUNKTE_OS.triggerRepaint()
....
```

If there is no other solution, how can I close the attribute table of the joined layer before the new join is set?

I know, there is the `showAttributeTable()` method. Is there also a `closeAttributeTable()` method?

It works when I close the specific attribute table in the `def __init__(self, parent):` function on Plugin startup. It doesn't work when I close the specific attribute table in the function where I set the joins (`setJoin(self)`).

Here is a sample of my code:

```py
class mask_n_functions(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):

def __init__(self, parent):
    QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    ...
    attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName() == u'QgsAttributeTableDialog' or d.objectName() == u'AttributeTable' ]
    for x in attrTables:
        if 'attr_table' in x.windowTitle():
            x.close()

def setJoin(self):
    prjpath = QgsProject.instance().fileName()
    ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### For QGIS 3

- If **only one** attribute table is opened:

  ```py
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

  all_widgets = QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
  attribute_table_widgets = [widget for widget in all_widgets if "AttributeTable" in widget.objectName()]
  attribute_table_widgets[0].close()
  ```
- If **multiple** attribute tables are opened:

  ```py
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

  all_widgets = QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
  attribute_table_widgets = [widget for widget in all_widgets if "AttributeTable" in widget.objectName()]
  for attribute_table in attribute_table_widgets:
      attribute_table.close()
  ```
- If **specific** attribute table(s) has to be closed:

  ```py
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

  all_widgets = QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
  attribute_table_widgets = [widget for widget in all_widgets if "AttributeTable" in widget.objectName()]
  for attribute_table in attribute_table_widgets:
      if 'PUNKTE' in attribute_table.objectName():
          attribute_table.close()
  ```

### For QGIS 2

- If **only one** attribute table is opened:

  ```
  from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

  all_widgets = QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
  attrTables = [widget for widget in all_widgets if widget.objectName() == u'QgsAttributeTableDialog' or widget.objectName() == u'AttributeTable']
  attrTables[0].close()
  ```
- If **multiple** attribute tables are opened:

  ```py
  from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

  all_widgets = QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
  attrTables = [widget for widget in all_widgets if widget.objectName() == u'QgsAttributeTableDialog' or widget.objectName() == u'AttributeTable']
  for attrTable in attrTables:
    attrTable.close()
  ```
- If **specific** attribute table(s) has to be closed:

  ```py
  from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

  all_widgets = QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
  attrTables = [widget for widget in all_widgets if widget.objectName() == u'QgsAttributeTableDialog' or widget.objectName() == u'AttributeTable']
  for attrTable in attrTables:
    if 'PUNKTE' in attrTable.windowTitle():
        attrTable.close()
  ```

Comment: How can I close the attribute table of the layer "PUNKTE"? How can I get the names of the QDialog list attrTables?

Comment: @Stefan - Edited my post to include an additional method. It's not a very direct method to closing attribute tables so I'm curious to see if there is a more efficient solution :). Note that the last method will close all attribute tables of layers which contains "PUNKTE" in their name. So ideally, you would want your layers to have ***unique*** names.

Comment: I tried a lot of combinations (closing one, multiple or distinct attribute table), but nothing works. There must be a difference between, there is no attribute table open and closing attribute table with the plugin and the methods in your answer. It is strange, closing attribute table this way seems not like closing it "with hand" a priori. I tried also to refresh all layers in the canvas.

Comment: @Stefan - Perhaps you can [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/231574/edit) your question to include the code you used for joining the layers and attempting to remove the attribute table.

Comment: It works when I close the specific attribute table in the `def __init__(self, parent):` function (calling plugin with panel). It doesn't work when I close the specific attribute table in the function where I set the joins.

Comment: @Stefan - I'm not sure...I did a test by connecting a function (which closes the attribute table) to a button and it works fine. Are you sure the name of the attribute table matches the name inside your function?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about the name. I've seen that it has closed after clicking a button (which sets the joins; `self.spatialite_join.clicked.connect(self.setJoin)`).

Answer (score 1):

a bit shorter:

first a list of all tables for a specific layer:

```
vlayer = iface.activeLayer()
filtered_widgets = [widget for widget in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if isinstance(widget,QDialog) and widget.objectName() == f"QgsAttributeTableDialog/{vlayer.id()}"]
```

then iterate and inspect...

```
for widget in filtered_widgets:
    print(f"'{widget.objectName()}'\
    \n\t'{type(widget)}'\
    \n\t{isinstance(widget,QDialog)}")
```

...or iterate and close:

```
for widget in filtered_widgets:
   widget.close()
```

**Caveat:**

Depends on the objectName of the attribute-table `"QgsAttributeTableDialog/layer.id()"` and the used Qt-Widget-Type `QDialog`, which might change in future QGis/Qt-Versions...