# Keeping attribute table open during QGIS close/re-open?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

When saving and closing QGIS with several open attribute tables, QGIS does not open these when opening the project next time. This is very annoying. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 6):

No, attribute table state (open or closed) cannot be saved.  The one work around I can think of is to use the Project menu>Project Properties openProject() python method to loop through the canvas layers and open them that way for a saved project.  See past Q/A of how to open an attribute table by code:

[Is it possible to open the attribute table using PyQgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68332/is-it-possible-to-open-the-attribute-table-using-pyqgis)

Comment: That is sad. Thanks anyway! Do you know whether this is considered as an issue among the developers?

Comment: Is that still the case in QGIS 3.28?