# PyQGIS Attribute table show selected features

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table

Is there a way to open attribute table at set the setting to "show selected features" through pyqgis?
[image]

Comment: For QGIS 2.x or 3.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can change the setting (which is available in `Settings > Options > Data Sources > Attribute table behaviour`) and set this to show selected features whenever the table opens:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().setValue("/Qgis/attributeTableBehaviour", "1")
```

[image: Attribute table behaviour]

---

**Edit:**

Using `iface.showAttributeTable(iface.activeLayer())` seems to ignore the QSetting and instead show all features as default. An alternative to load the attribute table of the **selected layer** with the chosen QSetting could be the following:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction
iface.mainWindow().findChild( QAction, 'mActionOpenTable' ).trigger()
```

Comment: And to open attribute table with pyqgis see this q/a, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68332/opening-attribute-table-using-pyqgis

Comment: Thanks, this works when i right click and opens attribute table, but not if i use iface.showAttributeTable(iface.activeLayer()). Do you know how I can get it to work with that?

Comment: @KasperSkjeggestad - Edited post :)

Comment: @KasperSkjeggestad - Most welcome, glad it helped :)

Comment: Please if your plugin change QSettings in the background, you should restore the previous value after that. I would hate a plugin changing my settings everytime I'm using it. Prefer the solution where you do not alter user settings.

Answer (score 7):

This is building on the [accepted answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/283883/107424) by [Joseph](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25814/joseph) but I don't have a enough reputation to comment on that. Anyone else searching for this may find the following useful to open an attribute table and then set its filter mode without needing to change the QSettings:

```
attDialog=iface.showAttributeTable(iface.activeLayer())  #Or specify a QgsVectorLayer 

attDialog.findChild(QAction,'mActionSelectedFilter').trigger()
```