# Using the advanced filter of an attribute table from python

Tags: pyqgis-3

I have created a script which opens the attribute table in QGIS and I would like to use the advanced filter (expression). I want to create the expression from python and then show the result in the attribute table.

Code:

```
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression( u'"STATUS" = \'OK\'' )
self.attDialog = self.iface.showAttributeTable(self.layer)
self.attDialog.findChild(QAction,'mActionAdvancedFilter').trigger()
```

Do you know how could I do that?

The expected result should be something like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you get any error when using the script below?

Comment: Nop. If you want to try it in the console, remove the 'self.' and assign layer = iface.activeLayer()

Comment: Where do you find 'mActionFieldFilter' ?

Comment: Sorry, its AdvancedFilter, just edited it @VincentBré

Comment: it does open a modal expression builder dialog when I try it on the console, confirm? (appologize my quick shot answer below...)

Comment: Yup @JochenSchwarze Ideally I would like to pass the expression via python and get the result as shown in the image.

Comment: Do you need to filter features in attribute table without filtering in map canvas, as "Advanced Filter (Expression)" does, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QGIS Python Editor version:

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *

layer = iface.activeLayer()

attDialog = iface.showAttributeTable(layer)

# firstly, you need get some widgets
mFilterButton = attDialog.findChild(QToolButton,'mFilterButton')
mActionAdvancedFilter = attDialog.findChild(QAction,'mActionAdvancedFilter')
mFilterQuery = attDialog.findChild(QLineEdit,'mFilterQuery')
mActionApplyFilter = attDialog.findChild(QAction,'mActionApplyFilter')

# set checked Advanced Filter (Expression)
mFilterButton.setDefaultAction(mActionAdvancedFilter)

# You can use string version of request
request = u'"STATUS" = \'OK\'' 
# add query string to the text box
mFilterQuery.setText(request)
mFilterQuery.setVisible(True)

# apply query
mActionApplyFilter.trigger()
```

[image]

Plugin version:

```py
self.attDialog = self.iface.showAttributeTable(self.layer)

mFilterButton = self.attDialog.findChild(QToolButton,'mFilterButton')
mActionAdvancedFilter = self.attDialog.findChild(QAction,'mActionAdvancedFilter')
mFilterQuery = self.attDialog.findChild(QLineEdit,'mFilterQuery')
mActionApplyFilter = self.attDialog.findChild(QAction,'mActionApplyFilter')

...
...
```

Comment: Amazing! This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

**Either**

You can pass the expression string directly to the `selectByExpression()` method of your `QgsVectorLayer` instance like this:

```
self.layer.selectByExpression('"STATUS" = \'OK\'')
```

`u'...'` is not needed since everything is unicode in Python 3.

Then you show the attribute table as shown above

```
self.attDialog = self.iface.showAttributeTable(self.layer)
```

and set its behaviour to only show the selected features

```
self.attDialog.findChild(QAction,'mActionSelectedFilter').trigger()
```

cp. [PyQGIS Attribute table show selected features](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283854/pyqgis-attribute-table-show-selected-features)

**Or**

If working with selections is unwanted one may apply a filter to the layer by

```
self.layer.setSubsetString(''"STATUS" = \'OK\''')
```

and open the attribute table.

Delete the filter by

```
self.layer.setSubsetString('')
```

Note that subset strings are plain sql.

cp. https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aba0ee124dcf2d037f3af53d99866c01c

Comment: I don't want to use 'mActionSelectedFilter' because if I select one of the selected features the rest of them will disappear from the attribute table.

Comment: got you. see my edit, possibly applying a filter is what you are looking for.

Comment: Your subsetString thing works fine but only if the layer is NOT in edit mode!