# Opening multiple attribute tables using .showAttributeTables()

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I've got a question about .showAttributeTables() - i'm trying to open two attrbute tables at the end of a query (selection of lines within a polygon layer) - I thought I could simply do somthing like this

```
# Spatial selection
cm_line = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("t_line")[0]
poly = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("t_poly")[0]

for i in cm_line.getFeatures():
    for l in poly.getFeatures():
        if i.geometry().within(l.geometry()):
            # add the selection to the layer
            cm_line.select(i.id())

# open tables
layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('t_poly')[0]
iface.showAttributeTable(iface.activeLayer())

layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('t_line')[0]
iface.showAttributeTable(iface.activeLayer())
```

But this opens the same table twice (the first one) - But I thought i'd changed the active layer here :
`layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName("t_line")[0]`  ??

Well, at least I didn't get an error message!

I should note that I've already seen this :
[Opening attribute table using PyQgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68332/opening-attribute-table-using-pyqgis)

and this tutorial here:
[pyqgis-101-viewing-vector-layer-attributes](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-viewing-vector-layer-attributes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in your own answer will work fine, but you could save yourself some typing (brevity & simplicity in code is a good thing and laziness is actually a useful trait for programmers!)

Since you already assigned both your layers to variables, you can simply do:

```
iface.showAttributeTable(cm_line)
iface.showAttributeTable(poly)
```

And just some additional info:

In the code you posted in your question, you were showing the attribute table for the **active layer**. That is whichever layer is highlighted in the layers panel, **not** the layer you were assigning to your `layer` variable. Making a layer active is usually achieved by clicking on its name in the layers panel, but you can also set it programmatically:

```
iface.setActiveLayer(cm_line) #pass a QgsMapLayer object
```

Comment: Thanks that helps, I like simple :)   I think I was confusing accessing a layer ('QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName()[0]') and activating layers (i.e. 'iface.setActiveLayer(cm_line)') .

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think I've worked this out myself in the end:

```
# spatial selection
cm_line = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("t_line")[0]
poly = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("t_poly")[0]

for i in cm_line.getFeatures():
    for l in poly.getFeatures():
        if i.geometry().within(l.geometry()):
            # add the selection to the layer
            cm_line.select(i.id())

# Open attrib tables
iface.showAttributeTable(QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('t_poly')[0])
iface.showAttributeTable(QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('t_line')[0])
```

It works fine in anycase! But would still be interested to hear if anyone has alternative solutions?